# jQuery: select text of an element with a particular attribute value

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to get the textual contents of the divs in the markup below. However, I can't seem to select the textual content of the div with class='ui-selected'. I need to "200", "x", "200". How do I get those?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.8.2r1/build/reset/reset-min.css">  <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.8.2r1/build/reset/reset-min.css">
<style>
    #selectable .ui-selecting { background-color:#2288FF; opacity:0.2; }
    #selectable .ui-selected { background-color:#2288FF; opacity:0.2; }
</style>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#selectable").selectable();
    });

    $(function() {
        $( "#selectable" ).selectable({
            stop: function() {
                $( ".ui-selected", this ).each(function() {
                    alert ($("div[class='ui-selected'].text"));
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<div id="selectable">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200"></img>
    <div style="position: absolute; width:33px; height:22px; left: 54px; top: 91px; font-size: 21px; color: transparent;">200</div>
    <div style="position: absolute; width:10px; height:22px; left: 92px; top: 91px; font-size: 21px; color: transparent;">x</div>
    <div style="position: absolute; width:33px; height:22px; left: 106px; top: 91px; font-size: 21px; color: transparent;">200</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$( ".ui-selected", this ).each(function() {
    alert ($("div[class='ui-selected'].text"));
 });
```

should be

```
var textyouwant = '';
$("div.ui-selected").each(function(){
    textyouwant += $(this).html();
});
alert(textyouwant);
```

Comment: the result of the alert was: `undefined200x200`. Any ideas why?

Comment: my first guess?  The image tag.  You'll need to filter that out.

Comment: the image tag is filtered out by `$("div.ui-selected")`, right? I think it's because of the containing `<div id="selectable">`. How do I exclude that?

Comment: Actually, you need to initialize `textyouwant` to an empty string, since the `+=` operator first tries to concatenate an undefined value with the string `"200"`. Everything else works out fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
alert ($("div[class='ui-selected'].text"));
```

should be

```
alert ($(".ui-selected").text());
```

I just corrected the syntax, but you need to take in consideration that `$('.ui-selected')` can match many items

Comment: I believe that will also select the img tag. I don't want that.